# Docker and hyper-v Issues

Tags: docker, hyper-v, windows-container

I want to configure docker with windows container. So i installed docker and enabled Hyper-v all features.

I have also execute this Command :

> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All

[image: Docker for windows]
Error this coming when i try to run docker for windows application

[image: cmd docker version]
Error coming when i execute docker version from CMD.

I've tried some solution on the google but the problem still remains.

Can someone knows how to solve?

**Edit:**
While execute command :

> New-VMSwitch -Name "minikube" -AllowManagement $True -NetAdapterName
>   "minikube"

Error comes :

> New-VMSwitch : Hyper-V encountered an error trying to access an object
>   on computer 'computer-name' because the object was not found. The object
>   might have been deleted. Verify that the Virtual Machine Management
>   service on the computer is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing hyperv after install docker it may work